# Regarding turning exact 180 degrees using an MPU6050

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I want to turn robot exact 180 degrees by using an MPU6050. This is the code I tried. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define enA 9
#define in1 4
#define in2 5
#define enB 10
#define in3 6
#define in4 7

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu6050.begin();
  mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);
  setupmotor();

}

void setupmotor(){
    pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
updatempu();

while(mpu6050.getAngleZ()== 180 || mpu6050.getAngleZ()== -180 ){
       turn();
  }

}

void updatempu(){
    mpu6050.update();
  Serial.print("\tangleZ : ");
  Serial.println(mpu6050.getAngleZ());

}


void turn(){
  Serial.println("turn");
        digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      analogWrite(enA, 100); // Send PWM signal to motor A
  analogWrite(enB, 100);
}

void stp(){
    Serial.println("stop");
        digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);

}
```

Comment: do you understand that `while(mpu6050.getAngleZ()== 180 || mpu6050.getAngleZ()== -180 )` is true when getAngleZ **IS** either 180 or -180? perhaps you meant `while(mpu6050.getAngleZ()!= 180 && mpu6050.getAngleZ()!= -180 )`

Comment: when mpu6050.getAglez() = 180 0r -180 then robot should stop. but it is not happening. without stopping ,it is turning

Comment: your logic *as it stands now* is, if `getAngleZ()` is 180 OR -180, call the function `turn` - but you want to turn if getAngleZ is NOT 180 AND NOT -180 - is that correct

Comment: if(mpu6050.getAngleZ()== 180 || mpu6050.getAngleZ()== -180 ){
       stp();
  }                                                                else { turn();} it should be like this or not??

Comment: maybe, I don't know, seems about right - did you try?

Comment: you are asking for help, but you do not say what the problem is. .... the information about what you observe should be in the question above .... please add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want the robot to position itself automatically at either 180° or -180° and stay there. When an outer force get's applied to the robot - turning it out of the target positions - it should again try to reach the target positions.

The first problem was pointed out in the comments and your own code correction seems ok to tackle that:

```
if(mpu6050.getAngleZ()== 180 || mpu6050.getAngleZ()== -180 ){
    stp();
} else {
    turn();
}
```

But I see a second problem: In the real world sensor mostly have some kind of noise imposed on their signal (not necessarily meaning electrical noise). For example if you shake the table, where the robot stands on. Or - more importantly in my opinion - The motor, that you use, might not stop fast enough. The MPU might return a value of 179° or 181° when it should be at 180°, because the motor could stop the robot fast enough (inside the time span it needs to travel 1°). In your current logic, this would trigger another turn command. Since you are only turning in one direction, this can create an instable system, which will turn infinitely.

This kind of problem is often solved by using a feedback loop control (of course in combination with the ability to control/turn into both directions). A good and useful example is a PID control (Proportional, Integral, Differential: This is how the control is mathematically structured), where there are already Arduino libraries for it (like [this one](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIDLibrary)). If you want it easier, you can define a range of angles, which are acceptable for your positioning (where it should stop) (for example 175° to 185°). The size of the range, that you need, would depend on the mechanics of your robot and the motor. Note, that this also has drawbacks, but it might be easier for now, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

---

As Tom pointed out in his comment, you also get trouble with your first approach, if the method `getAngleZ()` returns not an integer, but a float, which it indeed does. You can see this in the source code of the used library [here](https://github.com/tockn/MPU6050_tockn/blob/master/src/MPU6050_tockn.h). The line

```
float getAngleZ(){ return angleZ; };
```

tells us, that the return type of the method is `float`. The problem with this type is, that it cannot represent every rational value inside it's range. There are gaps between two following float values. The values inside this gap cannot be represented by float. Instead a value nearby will be used (Actually I'm not sure, how this is been done. Probably by going to the next lower value, like with `int`). This also means, that not every integer is representable by float. Even if the Z angle is exactly 180°, the float value may be something like `179,98`. But since `179,98` is not equal too `180` the statement

```
mpu6050.getAngleZ() == 180
```

would never become true. Of course the mentioned solutions above apply here too.

Comment: I completely agree, and I would also check that `getAngleZ()` returns an integer, not a float or double.

Comment: You are right, I have not thought of this. I will add it to the answer. thx